# Uncaught ReferenceError: testing is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I know this kind of question has been asked tons of time before.

So sorry for that i am new to react js, JavaScript etc. And i am using react app tool for this project.

I am preparing login form. So feature is simple when user click on login button. function should be called.

my function is in src/xyz and i want it to invoke from my index.html. but it fails. and give exception

- public

  - index.html
  - see.js
- src

  - xyz.js

```js
//my code in src/xyz.js

function testing(){
    console.log("welcome user")
}


//this code works which is in same directory
// public/see.js
function hello(){
    console.log("hi")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="/src/index.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="./see.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="/src/xyz.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="root">
    <h1>Login form</h1>
    <table id=login>
      <tr>
        <td>UserName</td>
        <td><input type="email" /> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>password</td>
        <td><input type="password" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" id="login" onclick="testing()">Log In</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are allowing access to `src` folder??

Answer (score 1):

it's from your src attribute, notice that you have "./" for see.js and just "/src/xyz"
you should probably change it to "./src/xyz.js"

```html
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="./see.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="/src/xyz.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

first you know react structure in react you don't invoke js file into public/index.html but using src/index.js file you access all the content.
all file import in src/index.js